# Stars and Bars variation

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to pit $m$ balls in $n$ buckets if the balls and buckets are distinguishable ie each bucket is labeled with numbers $1$ through $n$ and each ball is a different color?

Based on the negative comments, I do not want any new answers. The answer below is sufficient for the question.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: well...I know star and bar approach

Comment: but doesn't seem directly applicable

Comment: Probably the answer is in $\binom{\text{something}}{\text{different something}}$ form

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Usually in these problems the goal is to put the balls into the buckets, not the other way round.  If that's what you meant, then...how many choices are there for the first ball?  How many for the second ball?

Comment: The question isn't clear.  If all the balls are of different colours and they are already in the buckets, then the buckets are irrelevant.  For example if there is a red ball in bucket 1 and no other red balls, then "pick a red ball from bucket 1" is the same as "pick a red ball".

Comment: Changed the question...oops

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Each of* the $m$ distinct balls can be placed into *one* among the $n$ distinct buckets, and there are no restrictions on amount of balls contained by any bucket.

So count the ways to make $m$ independent selections of $n$ options.

---

PS the "stars and bars" method is inapplicable for this task, since we are dealing with distinctive 'stars'.